# Unit testing mysql rollback on node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, unit-testing, deadlock

I'm using mysql in a node project.

I would like to unit test a javascript function that makes an sql transaction. If the transaction becomes the victim of a lock monitor, the function has code that handles the failure.

*Or does it?*

Because I'm unit testing, I'm only making one transaction at a time on a local database, so there's never going to be a deadlock, right? How can I test the deadlock handling if it's never going to happen? Is there a way I can force it to happen?

Example:

```
thisMustBeDoneBeforeTheQuery();
connection.queryAsync(/*This is an update*/).catch(function(err) {
    undoThatStuffIDidBeforeTheQuery();
    // I hope that function worked, because my unit tests can't
    // make a deadlock happen, so I can't know for sure.
}
```

Comment: You should mock away the database stuff and in a test case fake the deadlock error. Then you can test for the validity of your error code. It depends on your use-case. Unit tests dealing with a persistence layer can become quite irky to setup. It also depends on how your code looks like for the proper testing strategy.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389149/how-do-you-mock-mysql-without-an-orm-in-node-js

Comment: It seems like mocking SQL might work.  I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

What is the essential behavior that your tests need to guard or verify?? Do you need to test your mysql driver? Or MySql itself?  I think @k0pernikus Identified the highest value test:

**Assuming that the database client results in an exception because of a deadlock, how does your application code handle it?**

You should be able to pretty easily create a test harness using a mocking library or Dependency Injection and test stubs to simulate the client driver returning a deadlock exception.  This shouldn't require any interaction with mysql, beyond the initial investigation to see what the return code/error exception propagation looks like for your mysql client driver.

This isn't a 100% perfect test, and still leaves your vulnerable in the case the mysql client library changes.

---

Reproducing concurrent issues deterministically is often times extremely difficult because of timing.  But using [`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432370/mysql-innodb-dead-lock-on-select-with-exclusive-lock-for-update) and multiple transactions should be able to deterministically reproduce a deadlock on mysql, to verify your client libraries code.